# Azure SQL performance is same with various vCore options

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

We are testing one feature in our enterprise application with Azure.
It try to Insert / Update / Delete / Fetch around 110K rows , The Java Web App is deployed in local machine , And we tried Local On Premise SQL Vs Azure Various hardware options , the difference is huge.
Local Machine Hardware : Intel i7 , 14 Core Cpu 32 GB RAM,
Local On Premise SQL Server 2019 also in same hardware.

when we run the feature locally in this hardware the whole operation gets completed in **4 Minutes**.

But when run the same feature with Azure SQL Database ( General Purpose vCore 2 Provisioned installation ) its taking around **20 Minutes.**

The confusing part here is when we tried to scale up the Azure DB to

**vCore - 4 ,
vCore - 6 ,
vCore - 10,
DTU Based Premium Option with 250 DTU's**

in all cases the timing almost same , no improvement.

**When we check the usage metrics in Azure portal , all metrics showing  CPU / IO usage are under 10% for all combinations(vCore 2,4,6,10).**

Now the question is what is the standard way to Connect/Configure Azure SQL DB from local machine to gain maximum performance for long data intensive work.

And why the increase in Azure capacity not achieving any performance improvements ?

Comment: Start with the Query Store.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16  And ensure your code not running a large number of single-row INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE without batching them in a transaction.

Comment: If your program is local it sounds like you're having overhead in the network. Do you use bulk import, perhaps you should. The ms tds protocol is kinda chatty over the non LAN. Unpopular opinion perhaps but On prem rules mostly anyway, so it can be that also

Comment: How much of your 20 minutes is network transfer back to your on-prem testing computer? MS-TDS suffers horribly under WAN/mobile network conditions because of the increased latency. Try repeating your tests from a machine or VM that's geographically closer to the Azure SQL databases - preferably in the same network or even on the same machine.